# how to print javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, printing

I would like to mention here I am very new to the JavaScript. I have following JavaScript object array. but how could I print those values in the browser as well? it is not going to print **document.write(vehicle);**

```js
var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:0005},
                  {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:0006}];

document.write(vehicle);
```

Comment: could i print it using document.write();

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Yousername Van 4 005 and Bus 6 006

Comment: [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.Stringify` would do.

```js
var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:0005},
                  {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:0006}];

document.write(JSON.stringify(vehicle));
```

To print just the values -

```js
var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:0005}, {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:0006}];

    document.write(
      vehicle
        .map(v => Object.values(v)) // retrive values from objects
        .flat()   // make linear array
        .join("<br/>")    // for new line as separator
    );
```

Comment: i need print only values here

Comment: ok @Robin, I updated the code that hopefully does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood what you wanted your code to do, but in order to print the contents of your objects in 'vehicle' array, I would suggest this:

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
      var vehicle = [
        { name: "Van", wheel: 4, chasino: 0005 },
        { name: "Bus", wheel: 6, chasino: 0006 }
      ];
      const container = document.createElement("div");

      for (const objIndex of vehicle) {
        const list = document.createElement("ul");
        list.setAttribute("class", objIndex);
        for (const key in objIndex) {
          const liElement = document.createElement("li");
          liElement.innerHTML = `${key}:${objIndex[key]}`;
          list.appendChild(liElement);
        }
        container.appendChild(list);
      }
      body.appendChild(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
        var s = String(this); 
        while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
        return s;
    }    
    
    var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:0005},
                          {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:0006}];
        
        for(i=0;i<vehicle.length;i++){
           document.write(vehicle[i].name+" "+vehicle[i].wheel+" "+vehicle[i].chasino.pad(3)+" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:0005},
               {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:0006}];
            
document.write(
  vehicle.map(a => Object.values(a).join(' '))
  .join('<br>')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the string `'0005'` instead of number to preserve the `'000'` characters.

```js
var vehicle = [{name:'Van',wheel:4,chasino:'0005'},
               {name:'Bus',wheel:6,chasino:'0006'}];
            
document.write(
  vehicle.map(a => Object.values(a).join(' '))
  .join('<br>')
);
```

Comment: but not in my side

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
vehicle.map(v => {
    document.write(v.name)
    document.write(v.wheel)
    document.write(v.chasino)
})
```